# Sequence.NEXTVAL in Oracle 12c with rs.getInt() or getLong() fails - so what datatype it returns?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, sequence

I am fetching next value of sequence with the `ps = connection.prepareStatement("select seq.nextval from dual");`
But neither `getLong()` nor `getInt()` works.
So how to correctly get the value from the `ResultSet` then?

full code:

```
public static long seqGetNextValue(String sequence) {
    Connection connection = Util.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Long value = new Long(0);

    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("select ? from dual");
        ps.setString(1, sequence);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            value = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Next payment Id: " + value);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Util.close(connection, rs, ps);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The exception is below, for `getInt` it looks the same:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getLong(CharCommonAccessor.java:258)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getLong(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:562)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getLong(GeneratedStatement.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getLong(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getLong(DelegatingResultSet.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getLong(DelegatingResultSet.java:228)
    at util.Util.seqGetNextValue(Util.java:85)
```

Comment: Did you check `if ( rs.next() )`? Perhaps you got the name of the sequence wrong.

Comment: "*does not work*" is not a known Oracle error message. What **exactly** is the error you get? Exception Stacktrace?

Comment: As above, please post the error encountered when you try the methods mentioned.

Comment: And also, please post the full code snippet!

Comment: Yes, I checked if ( rs.next() ). Sorry, I'll change my post.

Comment: Are you saying your `sequence` string is the literal `"seq.netxval"`?

Comment: @AlexPoole actually its `seq_ntid.nextval` but does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PreparedStatement`s cannot bind object names, just values. If you attempt to bind `seq.nextval` as you're doing above, you're actually binding **the string literal `'seq.nextval'`**, so your code is effective doing the following:

```sql
SELECT 'seq.nextval' -- Note that this is a string!
FROM   dual
```

Now it's obvious why `getInt` and `getLong` don't work - you aren't querying a number.

TL;DR - you cannot bind a sequence's name, and should just hard-code it in the statement (or use string manipulation/concatination to create the query). Once you've done that, you can use either `getInt` or `getLong`, depending on the values you expect to get. E.g.:

```
try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement("select " + sequence + " from dual");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        value = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Next payment Id: " + value);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    Util.close(connection, rs, ps);
}
```

Comment: Now it works, thank you, I understood the problem. Very good experience for me.